# How to read the lowest level node in a nested SOAP response

Tags: c#, soap

I have a nested loop in the SOAP response and I want to read the lowest level value from the loop. How can I write a recursive logic in C# to do the same? Below is my sample SOAP request

```
<hierarchy>
    <company company_id="ABC" name="ABC">
        <company company_id="DEF" name="DEF">
            <company company_id="1234" name="1234">
                <company company_id="5678" name="5678">
                    <company company_id="1000" name="1000">
                    </company>
                </company>
            </company>
        </company>
    </company>
</hierarchy>
```

I wanted to write a logic which is something like if company does not have anymore child nodes then read that value. FYI, this nested loop is dynamic meaning some SOAP response can have 5 nested companies and some can have 3.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Never nest the same the same tags like you are doing.  You are making it very hard to parse!!! Why not write something that is easier to parse?

Comment: This is not what I am writing, this is want I am getting as a response from a third party web service and I cannot change their response.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? If I understood your problem correctly.

```
public void foo(XmlNode node)
{
    if (node.HasChildNodes)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < node.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
        {
            foo(node.ChildNodes[i]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //read value
    }
}
```